# Is it possible to create a bash script instead of typing all these commands?

Tags: shell-script

The commands I have type everytime I want to start cad at school.

```
ssh -X naum.ad.liu.se
tcsh
source /sw/defaults/dotfiles/.tcsh rc
module load kurs/eks
module load TSEK06
source .TSEK06_rc
cad
```

Trying the solution suggested by muru gives me

```
source: Too few arguments.
bash: line 1: module: command not found
bash: line 2: module: command not found
.TSEK06_rc: line 2: setenv: command not found
.TSEK06_rc: line 3: setenv: command not found
.TSEK06_rc: line 4: setenv: command not found
.TSEK06_rc: line 5: /cshrc/tcshrc: No such file or directory
bash: line 4: cad: command not found
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you explain in more detail what you tried after putting these commands into the script? If possible, edit your question to add example input/output from your console command-line with which you tried to start the script, and the resulting messages (if any).

Comment: The errors from running one of the solutions should be a comment on that answer instead of part of the original question. It's possible to use something like pastebin.com or a GitHub gist to create a link to text that has several lines of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy thing to do, is to create a script at the server you are ssh-ing into:

Save this as `runcad.sh` at the server (either using `ssh` or something like `filezilla`):

```bsh
#!/bin/tcsh
source /sw/defaults/dotfiles/.tcshrc
module load kurs/eks
module load TSEK06
source .TSEK06_rc
cad
```

Then make it executable with `chmod +x runcad.sh`.

In theory, it should then be possible to:

```
ssh -X naum.ad.liu.se ./runcad.sh
```

On your machine, you could even create an alias for this:

```
alias cad="ssh -X naum.ad.liu.se ./runcad.sh"
```

Comment: I updated my question and pasted the output from the console. Would this not give me the same error as the one I get when I try muru's solution?

Comment: No, if `tsch` is placed in the path by the initial shell configuration, when running `ssh`, I believe the result may differ. Also `-c` can be harder to get right. You would just have to try it.

Comment: Got this result trying this. https://imgur.com/a/y1tU2Fb

Comment: Thanks for showing the output! There is something highly unusual about the setup on the host you are `ssh`-ing into. If you log in with `ssh` and type `which tsch`, which path do you get back? And does `/sw/defaults/dotfiles/.tcsh` actually exist?

Comment: I guess it have to exist cause I get nothing on the output. which tcsh gives me /bin/tcsh. https://imgur.com/a/Hz8kPph

Comment: This is a mystery! `source /sw/defaults/dotfiles/.tcsh rc` should complain if the files does not exist, yet the `runcad.sh` script complains that `/sw/defaults/dotfiles/.tcsh` does not exist. Is there either some special mounting or file generation going in when you log in with `ssh`? Could you please try replacing the `source` line in `runcad.sh` with all the lines from `/sw/defaults/dotfiles/.tcsh` and `rc` (if found) and see if that works?

Comment: I found the problem now. The file is ```source /sw/defaults/dotfiles/.tcshrc``` not ```source /sw/defaults/dotfiles/.tcsh rc```. Now it works perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it works now. Tip for the future: the `ls` or `stat` commands can be used to check if a file actually exists. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three shells involved here:

1. Your initial shell, where you type:

   ```
   ssh -X naum.ad.liu.se
   ```
2. The shell started by SSH, where you type:

   ```
   tcsh
   ```
3. And the tcsh you just started, where you type:

   ```
   source /sw/defaults/dotfiles/.tcsh rc
   module load kurs/eks
   module load TSEK06
   source .TSEK06_rc
   cad
   ```

If you dumped all these lines in a script and ran it, your initial shell would be running all of them.

If you just need to start `cad` and don't need an interactive shell, you could condense it to a single command run by your initial shell:

```
ssh -X naum.ad.liu.se tcsh -c 'source /sw/defaults/dotfiles/.tcsh rc
module load kurs/eks
module load TSEK06
source .TSEK06_rc
cad'
```

And put that in a script. This tells SSH to run `tcsh -c '...'`, which tells tcsh to run the part following `-c` as commands.

Comment: When I try that script I get  
source: Too few arguments.  
bash: line 1: module: command not found  
bash: line 2: module: command not found  
.TSEK06_rc: line 2: setenv: command not found  
.TSEK06_rc: line 3: setenv: command not found  
.TSEK06_rc: line 4: setenv: command not found  
.TSEK06_rc: line 5: /cshrc/tcshrc: No such file or directory  
bash: line 4: cad: command not found

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you actually tried. You're getting errors from bash, not tcsh, whereas the script in my answer runs tcsh

Comment: You haven't shown what you actually ran, though.

Comment: This is how I ran it. https://imgur.com/a/8blpdMr